# Error after add to whistlist Magento 2.2.4

Tags: wishlist, magento2.2.4

I have installed the `Magento 2.2.4` and market place theme pioneer. I have tried to add to wishlist the product but I am getting below error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\ConfiguredOptions::getItemOptionsValue()
>   must be of the type float, boolean given, called in
>   /var/www/html/gomm/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/ConfiguredRegularPrice.php
>   on line 74 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/gomm/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/ConfiguredOptions.php:24
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/gomm/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/ConfiguredRegularPrice.php(74):
>   Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\ConfiguredOptions->getItemOptionsValue(false,
>   Object(Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item)) #1
>   /var/www/html/gomm/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/BasePrice.php(32):
>   Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\ConfiguredRegularPrice->getValue() #2
>   /var/www/html/gomm/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/FinalPrice.php(44):
>   Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\BasePrice->getValue() #3
>   /var/www/html/gomm/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/ConfiguredPrice.php(101):
>   Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice in
>   /var/www/html/gomm/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/ConfiguredOptions.php
>   on line 24

Comment: Hi Jack, Please check the product price which you are adding in wishlist. Because by default Magento does not allow the zero product (0.00).

Answer (score 3):

The error is caused due to the product price is zero.

Since in default Magento while adding the wishlist the product price type is return as "float".

Refer the coding line: 24 in below file path

vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/ConfiguredOptions.php

Can you change the product price and then check it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `generation/code`

Run command:

> bin/magento cache:flush
>
> bin/magento setup:di:compile

Hope it will work.

Comment: I have tried but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is the bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16479
You can choose one of options:

1. Remove zero price product from wishlist
2. Update Magento to v2.3.0 or upper
3. Install patch, if you install Magento within composer you have to patch with [0fc1574](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/0fc15747f05571cd6b164c01e1f1b6168e37a468) commit using [this manual for patch installing](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005484154-Create-a-patch-for-a-Magento-2-Composer-installation-from-a-GitHub-commit)

   Link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16479#issuecomment-421576285